# open\closed and disjoint sets under R2

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I am stuck with the following question:

Consider the sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by
$A = \{(x,1/x)| x > 0 \}$, $B = \{(x, −1/x)| x < 0\}$.
Prove that the sets are closed and disjoint, and that $d(A, B) = 0$ and that
there are no $a_0 \in A$, $b_0 \in B$ for which $d(a_0, b_0) = d(A, B)$.

i have a couple of issues here.

- for close sets i thought of proving $A$'s and $B$'s commentaries are open. but i don't know how to represent their commentaries. is this a good approach?
- what is the mining of disjoints and how do i prove it?

I am new to metric spaces in general so please don't assume i posses any prior knowledge on the subject.

Thanks

Comment: It is obvious they are disjoint because all points of $A$ have $x>0$ and all points of $B$ have $x<0$. It is obvious $d(A,B)=0$ because the two points $(k,1/k),(-k,1/k)$ are a distance $2k$ apart which can be made as small as we like. It is obvious that we cannot find $a_0\in A,b_0\in B$ with $d(a_0,b_0)=0$ because then $a_0$ would belong to $A$ and $B$. So the only thing left to consider is why $A$ is closed. It is closed if it contains its limit points. So suppose $(x,y)$ was a limit point of $A$, but not in $A$. What would that imply?

Comment: i still don't get what are disjoint sets? what is the definition?
it would imply that (x,y) resides in B? if so how does it proves A is closed?

Comment: Disjoint sets are sets which do not have a common point. In other words, two sets are disjoint iff there does not exist a point which belongs to both of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some hints:

- For $d(A,B)=0$: Note that $(a,\frac{1}{a})\in A$ for all $a>0$, and for any such $a>0$ we also have $(-a,\frac{1}{a})\in B$. Then
  \begin{align*}
  d(A,B)\leq d\Big((a,\frac{1}{a}),(-a,\frac{1}{a})\Big).
  \end{align*}
  Calculate this distance and conclude by taking $a\to 0$.
- For closedness, you may write $A=\{(x,y)\in F:y-\frac{1}{x}=0\}\cap \{(x,y):x\geq 0\}$ and where $F=\Bbb{R}^{2}\setminus B(0,1)$, where $B(0,1)$ is an open ball radius $1$ centered at zero. $F$ is closed because its complement is open, and $A$ is an intersection of two closed sets (recall that the preimage of a closed set under a continuous function is closed).
- For disjointness: Note that each point in $A$ has a positive $x$-coordinate, while each point in $B$ has a negative $x$-coordinate. Then, is it possible that there exists a point in $A\cap B$? (The definition of $A$ and $B$ being disjoint is if $A\cap B=\emptyset$.)

Comment: can you kindly explain this notation? F=R2∖B(0,1)

Comment: @havakok. If $X$ and $Y$ are two sets, $X\setminus Y$ is the set of elements that are in $X$ but not in $Y$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot @T.Eskin

Comment: One more Question, the continuous function here is d(A,B)?

Comment: @havakok. The continuous functions are $(x,y)\mapsto y-\frac{1}{x}$ and $(x,y)\mapsto x$.